# How to avoid gaps appearing in Freestyle lines?

Tags: rendering, lighting, freestyle, outliner, render-border

[image]

How can I avoid these breaks when rendering outline using freestyle ?

[image]

https://drive.google.com/file/d/16dK_Q-b8PJ3QYIaJNwdPlHQp2GODaXQU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org). Photos are harder to read because we have to look past external interferences (like reflections, smudges or Moiré patterns) and guess if we are looking at hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connections, a software level issue like driver malfunction or glitch, or actual artifacts or issues with the model itself.

Comment: Hi. Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.